# android app update and resuming activity

Tags: android, dialog

I am developing one app and in that app I am checking the current version and latest version of using JSOUP and according to latest vesuion showing dialog to update the app.

But U want to make update compulsary. so I make dialog `cancallable=false` the main problem is that when user click on update it open playstore with app

I want to when user return from playstore i want to hide the dialog,

then how should I do this. If user doesn't updated then display dialog as it is and when update is completed then hide dialog.

Comment: After update you need to restart the app, don`t you? So what is the point of resuming to app

Comment: does it automatic process or do manually

Answer (score 0):

App update is nothing but it will reinstall the new apk from play store, so after reinstall app is considered as updated, in this case your app will be restarted automatically by the system.

In your case app will be restarted after update so you no need to handle onResume.

Comment: How to make my dialog uncancelable\